# How to change the URL in ember.js by checking platform?

Tags: ember.js, tornado, ember-paper

I am new to ember.js.

I want to know about changing url by checking platform. I have two web app for mobile view server and web view server which are created by ember.js and tornado webserver.They are same app but different ui for mobile and web. when i type the url www.something.com in mobile browser, i want to go to the url m.something.com in mobile view server automatically and if i type the www.something.com in desktop browser, it should go to web view server automatically.

I don't know how to do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

[ember-bowser](https://github.com/akatov/ember-bowser) should do what you need.

I would suggest ditching the different UIs for mobile and web and go with a responsive mobile first approach using something like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)